# move moodle module from resources to activities

Tags: php, moodle

I'm working on a moodle module, and when I arrived on this project, the module was already created. The problem is when I'm trying to add it in a course, the module appears in the resources section and I would like to put it in the activities section. How can I do that?
[The pop up where I want my module to appear as activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkE1O.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, that separates modules into groups, simply checks the constant prefixed MOD_ARCHETYPE_:

```
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $activityclass = MOD_CLASS_ACTIVITY;
        if ($module->archetype == MOD_ARCHETYPE_RESOURCE) {
            $activityclass = MOD_CLASS_RESOURCE;
        } else if ($module->archetype === MOD_ARCHETYPE_SYSTEM) {
            // System modules cannot be added by user, do not add to dropdown.
            continue;
        }
        $link = $module->link->out(true, $urlparams);
        $activities[$activityclass][$link] = $module->title;
    }
```

As we can see, it simply checks "archetype" property.

Find function YOURMODULENAME_supports in /mod/yourmodulename/lib.php

It should have a string like

```
case FEATURE_MOD_ARCHETYPE:           return MOD_ARCHETYPE_RESOURCE;
```

Comment it out. The module should now be in activity section (default)